# Add white spaces to the end of the string

Tags: excel

I have a list of strings, each of different length. e.g.

```
AUSTRALIA
CANADA
EUROPE
GERMANY
GREAT BRITAIN
HONG KONG
```

I need each cell to be 20 characters in length.
For example, `AUSTRALIA` has 9 characters, in that case I would need to add 11 more whitespaces at the end of the string for the `=len()` to be a total of 20 characters.

I have done this before, but I can not remember the function which adds characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula you need is [`REPT`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/rept-function-04c4d778-e712-43b4-9c15-d656582bb061).

Assuming that your text is in column A, you can paste this in column B and apply it to all relevant cells:

```
=A1 & REPT(" ", 20 - LEN(A1))
```

Comment: Slightly simpler would be `=LEFT(A1&REPT(" ",20),20)`.